# Applying sonarqube for remote repository

Tags: github, sonarqube, gitlab, sonarqube-scan, sonar-runner

I have a project in my github.Sonarqube was running in local machine(windows).Now I want to apply sonarqube on my repository project in my local machine only without using jenkins.

I have applied the sonarqube when that project is in local machine.

Two requirements I want to do
1)Applying sonarqube to remote repository
2)whenever a commit happens update sonarqube on that changes.

Answer (score 0):

> Applying sonarqube to remote repository

That means a remote process running Sonar on the GitHub side.
For now, you have [GitHub Actions](https://github.com/features/actions) which allow, on push, to run specific programs.

For instance: [`sonarsource/sonarcloud-github-action`](https://github.com/sonarsource/sonarcloud-github-action) will run [SonarCloud](https://sonarcloud.io/) (you can sign up an account for free) in order to detects bugs, vulnerabilities and code smells in more than 20 programming languages.

No Jenkins required.